# Preloading a “fetch” resource for use in a web worker

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker, preload

**tl;dr** Resources pre-loaded as

```html
<link rel="preload" href="..." as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

don’t seem to be used by a `fetch` call that occurs in a Web Worker.

Why is this? Is there a change I need to make to the preload tag, or another workaround?

---

**Context:** I have a Web Worker which downloads and processes a large amount of CSV data. The processing is quite intensive, so I’d like to keep it off the main thread.

However, I’d love a way to initiate the download earlier, so that the worker can get start processing it sooner after the worker starts.

I tried adding add a `<link rel="preload" as="fetch" ...>` for the resource, and that works great for a fetch from the *main* thread—but if I fetch the same resource from the worker, it the preloaded resource is *not* used (a separate request is initiated and I can see the standard “resource was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event” warning printed to the console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it seems that even though Workers do have the same (a clone) [Policy Container](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#policy-container) as their owner `Document`, that's about it, and the [map of preloaded resources](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#map-of-preloaded-resources) isn't shared.

So for your case what you could do is to preload in the main thread using your `<link>`, `fetch()` from there too, consume the `Response` as an `ArrayBuffer` (it's the rawest format) and transfer that `ArrayBuffer` to your `Worker`:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="..." as="fetch" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```js
  // ...
  const resp = await fetch("...");
  if (!resp.ok) { handleNetworkError(resp) }
  const buffer  = await resp.arrayBuffer();
  const worker = new Worker(/*...*/);
  worker.postMessage({ buffer }, [buffer]);
```

And in your `Worker` you'd do

```
  onmessage = ({ data }) => {
    if (data.buffer) {
      const csvText = new TextDecoder().decode(data.buffer);
      parseCSV(csvText);
    }
  };
```

Doing this way, you still take advantage of the preloading, and you still have a very minimal impact on the main thread: the fetching is done in parallel, consuming the `Response` as `ArrayBuffer` doesn't cost any computation, and neither should transferring the data to the `Worker`. But it's a bit more convoluted than just fetching from the `Worker` directly.

Another solution depending on your case might be to use a `ServiceWorker` to pre-fetch your resources and cache them. Your `Worker` would then be able to tap in the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! This seems like the most reasonable workaround.